# $ \frac{1}{f^2} $ Weighting for Least Squares FIR

Tags: finite-impulse-response, least-squares

I am currently modifying the `firls.m` from Octave to allow all types of FIRs, differentiators, and Hilbert transformers, while taking a peak at [Matlab's](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/firls.html). I see there that, for differentiators, the default weighting is `1/f^2`. In Selesnick's [paper](http://legacy.cnx.org/content/m10577/latest/) there's no mention of this. Does anyone know how to achieve it?

My thoughts go to $\int{K(\omega)\cos(n\omega)d\omega}$ (and the rest). Does it derive from $\int{K(\omega)^2\cos(n\omega)d\omega}$ ? Or from $\int{\left[\int{K(\omega)d\omega}\right]\cos(n\omega)d\omega}$ ? Does anyone have a hint?

---

I just thought of it this way: if it uses a $1/f^2$ weighting, doesn't that mean that the weighting $K(\omega)$ becomes $1/\omega^2$ ? So, the integral would become:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}{K(\omega)\cos(n\omega)d\omega}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}{\frac{\cos(n\omega)}{\omega^2}d\omega}$$

which is similar to the exponential cosine integral, without the log part. Further on there's:

$$\frac{in}{2}\left[\Gamma(-1,in\omega)-\Gamma(-1,-in\omega)\right]$$

The nice thing is that there is no imaginary part in the result. Maybe I'm hoping too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the page you link to says:

> `'differentiator'` for type III and type IV filters, using a special weighting technique. For nonzero amplitude bands, the integrated squared error has a weight of (1/f)2 so that the error at low frequencies is much smaller than at high frequencies. For FIR differentiators, which have an amplitude characteristic proportional to frequency, the filters **minimize the relative integrated squared error (the integral of the square of the ratio of the error to the desired amplitude).**

**Bolding** mine.

So, following the paper:
$$
\epsilon_2 = \int_0^\pi W(\omega)(A(\omega)−D(\omega))^2d\omega
$$
for the differentiator, we want:
$$
W(\omega) = \frac{1}{\omega^2}\\
D(\omega) = \omega
$$
and $A(\omega)$ has the same form as before.

So
$$
\epsilon_2 = \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{\omega^2}(A(\omega) - \omega)^2 d\omega\\
= \int_0^\pi \left[\frac{A^2(\omega)}{\omega^2} - 2\frac{A(\omega)}{\omega} + 1 \right] d\omega
$$
Just substitute the expression for $A(\omega)$ and you're done.

Comment: Isn't that a least-squares FIR's purpose? After all (quote from the same page): "`firls` designs a linear-phase FIR filter that minimizes the weighted, integrated squared error", which sounds very similar. This is simply something I'd rather not just throw darts. I could try various formulas, whichever seems about right, but I fear the results might not come close to what a true 1/f^2 weighting is. :-) I suppose I just want to be sure about this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand.  The weighting in `firls` can be chosen virtually arbitrarily. For differentiators, because their magnitude response is linear with frequency, they've chosen a relative error.  It's not clear to me what your question is....

Comment: The weights are constant over each band, e.g. for a band of `[0 pi/3]` the weight can only be a number, fixed, like `10`, but this 1/f^2 weighting means the weights change with frequency, so it's variable. For constant weights, there's the derivation in Selesnick's paper, but for 1/f^2, I don't know, not even where to start from, hence my few guesses in the question.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen : See my update. Does that help? I'm missing what you're missing.

Comment: I edited my question, but now, looking at both, I realize I forgot it's $K(\omega)D(\omega)$, which means, for $K(\omega)=1/\omega^2$ and $D(\omega)=\omega$ that the result is $1/\omega$, so then the integral becomes $\int{\frac{\cos(n\omega)}{\omega}d\omega}$, which is the cosine integral. This looks promising so I'll go on with this, see where it leads. Two brains are better than one, my grandpa always said. :-)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen : Sounds good. Ping me here if there is anything else that perturbs. :-)